# Pyinstaller networkx module issue

Tags: python-2.7, networkx, pyinstaller

I have one python file from networkx examples:

```
from networkx import Graph

G=Graph()
G.add_node("spam")
G.add_edge(1,2)
print(list(G.nodes()))
print(list(G.edges()))
```

Now i want use pyinstaller to build bin file

```
pyinstaller --debug --onedir nx.py
```

after building and running nx.exe i get this error in cmd:

```
PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x
LOADER: executable is C:\Users\XRP836\Desktop\MeshSim\ex\dist\nx\nx.exe
LOADER: homepath is C:\Users\XRP836\Desktop\MeshSim\ex\dist\nx
LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is NULL
LOADER: archivename is C:\Users\XRP836\Desktop\MeshSim\ex\dist\nx\nx.exe
LOADER: No need to extract files to run; setting extractionpath to homepath
LOADER: SetDllDirectory(C:\Users\XRP836\Desktop\MeshSim\ex\dist\nx)
LOADER: Already in the child - running user's code.
LOADER: Python library: C:\Users\XRP836\Desktop\MeshSim\ex\dist\nx\python27.dll
LOADER: Loaded functions from Python library.
LOADER: Manipulating environment (sys.path, sys.prefix)
LOADER: sys.prefix is C:\Users\XRP836\Desktop\MeshSim\ex\dist\nx
LOADER: Setting runtime options
LOADER: Initializing python
LOADER: Overriding Python's sys.path
LOADER: Post-init sys.path is C:\Users\XRP836\Desktop\MeshSim\ex\dist\nx
LOADER: Setting sys.argv
LOADER: setting sys._MEIPASS
LOADER: importing modules from CArchive
LOADER: extracted struct
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: extracted pyimod01_os_path
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: extracted pyimod02_archive
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: extracted pyimod03_importers
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: Installing PYZ archive with Python modules.
LOADER: PYZ archive: out00-PYZ.pyz
LOADER: Running pyiboot01_bootstrap.py
LOADER: Running pyi_rth_pkgres.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgres.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "c:\users\xrp836\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-hppbcz\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line
389, in load_module
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2958, in <module>
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2944, in _call_aside
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2986, in _initialize_master_working_set
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dist' referenced before assignment
Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres
LOADER: OK.
LOADER: Cleaning up Python interpreter.
```

as I understand it I need to create hook file for pyinstaller (hook-networkx.py), but i don't really know how to do it correctly. Or what i should do to fix that?

Comment: I am not sure that the problem is a missing hook. In any case, you can try to include --hidden-import=networkx or --hidden-import=networkx.Graph in your arguments to see if it works. More here:http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports.

Comment: @Repiklis same error after using proper hiddenimports in spec file or --hidden-import as argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by downgrading pyinstaller to 3.1 version.